# How to add custom constraints to ForeignKey relationships in django

Tags: django, django-models

Say I wanted to add an extra attribute to the `ForeignKey` relationship in `django` to allow further customization. 
Say for instance I want to add an attribute which when enabled will not allow repetitions ( I realize this particular use case already has a fix but it's just an  example). 
How would I approach such a  thing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the [next version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/) of django will contain the ability to define them on the model.

In the meantime, I think you'll need to create an empty migration and have it create the constraint manually via `migrations.RunSQL`